# Decrypt DES encrypted String back to plain text

Tags: java, encryption, des

I'm working on DES encryption algorithm. I am able to encrypt the plain text to cipher text, but I failed to decrypt the cipher text back to normal plain text.

**What converter I should use?**

Here is my code that used in my encryption method:

```
public static String encryptString(String src) throws Exception {
    String dst = "";

    SecretKey secret_key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
    AlgorithmParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(initialization_vector);
    encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key, alogrithm_specs);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cout = new CipherOutputStream(baos,encrypt);
    cout.write(src.getBytes());
    cout.flush();               //ByteOutputStream -> Write Encryption Text
    cout.close(); 
    dst = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(baos.toByteArray());
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: Failed in what way? Where's your decrypt code?

Comment: The key should be generated outside of the encrypt method. How else would you use it during decryption? Other than that, just change `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` to `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE`. I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: I improved the title to make it clear what the question is about. I also fixed a few typos in the questions text.